# Check if a browser has location settings blocked at an operating system level

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, geolocation

I have a site that for regulatory purposes requires the user's location (you can't access the site from ineligible states countries).

When a user logs in, I check `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` and if it fails, I handle the various returned error codes and alert the user if they have denied us use of the location in the browser (I'm specifically speaking about Chrome here).

However I've noticed lately that Mac OS in 'system preferences' > 'security & privacy' > 'location services' can occasionally turn off for Chrome. Whether this is from updates or because the user set it is not important to me.

What I want to know is if there is a way to query the browser api and find out if the OS has blocked location, so that I can provide a better error message to the user. If you have it blocked at the OS layer then `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` doesn't return anything, rather than if it's blocked at the browser level, you get an error.

I don't believe I'm getting anything back from `navigator.geolocation` that gives me that information - although I could be wrong. I've looked for the answer to this online, but everything seems to mention `navigator.geolocation` and I'm already handling that.

Let me know if this is unclear, but I'm trying to detect location settings from the OS at the browser level.

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to query OS level meta data using JavaScript inside a browser. [Spec](https://w3c.github.io/geolocation-api/#security)

Comment: @RandyCasburn Cheers, no I get that and I'm not trying to query the OS per se. I mean obviously the browser knows that location is blocked, so I'm wondering if the browser surfaces that anywhere that I can query. Like I want to ask the middleman rather than the OS

Comment: That's why I included a link to the spec. It will answer those questions. if you scroll down to the requirements for the user agent (browser) you will not see any requirement for the browser to support that, and there is no API in that spec to request that information.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Cheers, bit of a bugger that - big pain when trying to let the user know. I'll think of something, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@BrettEast you can use timeout parameter to work around like:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
  console.log(position)
}, error => {
    console.error(error)
}, {
  timeout: 10000,
  maximumAge: 10000,
  enableHighAccuracy: true
})
```

If the location will be off from OS, after 10000 ms, it will go in the error block
GeolocationPositionError {code: 3, message: "Timeout expired"}.
Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, I did try this, but ended up opting for a custom timeout method. I didn't want to kill the attempt on timeout, incase the user had a slow connection. After 6 secs I display a message to the user that they may be experiencing location issues. By not timing out, they can turn location back on and it will then work immediately without them needing to try again.